# StackOverflowError with AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I try to do authentication by tokens. I need a filter, which will check some token in header, and if it isn't valid - shows error.

That's what I have:

```java
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public TokenAuthenticationFilter() {
    super("/rest/**");
    setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
    {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String path = request.getServletPath() + (request.getPathInfo() != null ? request.getPathInfo() : "");
        request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
    });
    setAuthenticationFailureHandler((request, response, authenticationException) -> {
        response.getOutputStream().print(authenticationException.getMessage());
    });
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String token = request.getHeader("token");
    if (token == null)
        token = request.getParameter("token");
    if (token == null) {
        TokenAuthentication authentication = new TokenAuthentication(null);
        authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
        return authentication;
    }

    TokenAuthentication tokenAuthentication = new TokenAuthentication(token);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(tokenAuthentication);
    }
}
```

Config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .addFilterAfter(restTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/get/1").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/login").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Bean(name = "restTokenAuthenticationFilter")
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter restTokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        TokenAuthenticationFilter restTokenAuthenticationFilter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
        restTokenAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(tokenAuthenticationManager);
        return restTokenAuthenticationFilter;
    }
}
```

But there are StackOverflowError at this filter. It forward request every time to this filter. I think that it should be another `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

UPDATE: It's easy to solve the problem with using `GenericFilterBean` and just do `chain.doFilter(request, response);`, if token are valid, but how to do it with `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

Comment: `public TokenAuthenticationFilter()` constructor looks suspicious to me. As it is the default no-args constructor, it is called when `restTokenAuthenticationFilter` bean is created in `Security` class. Create separate methods for `setAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and `setAuthenticationFailureHandler` rather creating them in constructor

Comment: @harshavmb but what will it give?

Comment: @dur I understand, but if set a empty `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, it will be empty response. And another way - by default (if I dont override `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`), it redirect to main page (`/`). I need  behavior, similar with `FilterChain.doFilter(request, response)`, but I doesn't have `FilterChain` object here.

Comment: @dur , yes, I tried it. I already used GenericFilterBean for it. But it is a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: @dur you are right in most of cases. But in my it is a JWT authorization, that's why I should check this token on any URL. But I understood, that `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` isn't for this case.